# I cannot upload images in Wordpress library

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot upload images in Wordpress library. WP returns http error. All limits are sets to 1024 mb in htaccess and php.ini

Wordpress debug mode returns:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘wp_image_editors’ - assumed
>   '‘wp_image_editors’' in /xxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 5467
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘change_graphic_lib’ - assumed
>   '‘change_graphic_lib’' in /xxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 5467

What can i do?

Edit: line 5467 function.php

```
add_filter( ‘wp_image_editors’, ‘change_graphic_lib’ );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array( ‘WP_Image_Editor_GD’, ‘WP_Image_Editor_Imagick’ );
}
```

Comment: can you post your functions.php file line 5467

Comment: I edited post. Here you have

Comment: Looks like your are inserting strange quotes into your code. Make sure you are using `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong quotes.

Try:

```
add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib');

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array('WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick');
}
```